# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'seventh_five' despite the existence of the object

Tags: python, django

I am creating a website where a user can create a project. Each project has 10 macro-questions. Each macro-question has sub-questions.

I am trying to retrieve the answer to a macro-question.

`projects_id` contains all the projects in my database.

```
  projects = Project.objects.all()
  projects_id = []
  for project in projects:
    projects_id.append(project.id)
```

So I do a for loop:

```
  for project_id in projects_id:
    seventh_question_project = Seventhquestion.objects.all().filter(project=project_id).first()
    answer_seventh_five = seventh_question_project.seventh_five
        if answer_seventh_five == "No":
           unaudited_projects.append(answer_seventh_five)
        else:
           audited_projects.append(answer_seventh_five)
```

If I use the console, I am able to retrieve `answer_seventh_five`:

[image]

however, if load the page, I get:

> > 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'seventh_five'

Which I cannot explain since `answer_seventh_five` exists (as I tested it by retrieving it via console)

**MAYBE** the reason is that I am filtering and not getting the object with `get`.

I tried:

```
seventh_question_project = Seventhquestion.objects.get(project=project_id)
```

But I get:

> > Seventhquestion matching query does not exist.

However:     `seventh_question_project = Seventhquestion.objects.all()` works

Comment: You're looping through a bunch of `projects_id`, it just requires one of them to not exist for this error to happen. When you tried in your console, which of the ids did you try? Also, don't use `get()` since this is a one-to-many relationship by the looks of it, so this will throw exceptions if there are 0 or > 1 object.

Comment: I made sure that all the `projects_id` contains only existing projects. Please see the edit. The relationship is one-to-one between `project` and `Seventhquestion`. Each project can only have one Seventhquestion.

Comment: But it's not about the project existing, it's about a `SeventhQuestion` object existing that has a foreign key to the project. Also, if the field is `project` then you should filter like this: `filter(project=<some project instance>)` not by project_id. If you only have the ids, then `filter(project_id=project_id)`. FK fields refer to the actual objects, which is why in Django you usually don't pass ids around but the actual objects making code much more readable.

Comment: Use a debugger.  Put a breakpoint on the line `answer_seventh_five = seventh_question_project.seventh_five`.  Inspect `seventh_question_project` at each loop iteration.

Comment: I try to do it. Menawhile, if I set the `Seventhquestion.seventh_five` equal to something in the database, like `default="No`, will this solve the risk of not having the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't go via the ids. That's not what the Django ORM is made for. Just loop through the projects themselves:

```
for project in Project.objects.all():
    seventh_question_project = Seventhquestion.objects.all().filter(project=project).first()  # <-- not project_id!
    # or better:
    # seventh_question_project = project.seventhquestion_set.first()  
    if seventh_question_project:
        # you should always check, because you need to write fool-proof code
        answer_seventh_five = seventh_question_project.seventh_five
        ...
```

But with relationships, you have even much easier ways to fetch the related objects. So assuming the `project` field is a `OneToOneField` on the `Seventhquestion` model, than the reverse relationship is `seventhquestion`:

```
for project in Project.objects.all():
    if hasattr(project, "seventhquestion"):
        # still need to check, you never know
        answer_seventh_five = project.seventhquestion.seventh_five
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```js
seventh_question_project = Seventhquestion.objects.filter(project=project_id).first()
answer_seventh_five = seventh_question_project.seventh_five
```